# Where can I get a small text proofread?

Tags: support, appropriate-questions

I've just discovered this site hoping someone could proofread a small description of my new open-source project. However the FAQ specifically disallows it. Would anyone kindly point me to site that *does* offer this kind of service?

Answer (score 3):

The StackExchange network doesn't have anywhere offering proofreading. Expecting to find such at English.SE or Writers.SE is not unreasonable; however, both sites have declared proofreading off-topic as being too localized, and as a straightforward process of correcting technical errors, rather than questions to be answered or problems to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Our sister site [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) does accept critique requests (they have a [dedicated tag](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) for those). However, make sure that you meet [their guidelines](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work).

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic at Writers: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/301/should-we-allow-grammar-proofreading-questions . We do accept critique questions, but for something rather different.

Answer (score -1):

Last I checked, [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) was OK with proofreading requests.

> Writing critique questions are also welcome here, provided you tag them as critique – and provide details and context for your writing, as well as some direction on what type of feedback you're looking for.

Comment: Not any more: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/301/should-we-allow-grammar-proofreading-questions .